# Where file status info actually store?

Tags: file, unix, filesystems, stat

Where the file status info actually store when we using stat() in  to get?

I'am learning Unix Programing, But i am confused when i using stat() function to get file status. There are no any information about where the file info actually store.

```c
void do_stat(char *filename) {
  struct stat info;
  if (stat(filename, &info) == -1) {
    perror(filename);
  } else {
    show_file_info(filename, &info);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you use Unix check `man 2 stat` to get a descriptions of all fields in `stat` struct.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question, you should complete the basic knowledge about UNIX-like file system. You can get a basic impression in [here](http://digi-cron.com:8080/filesystems.html).

For your question: The files status info are store in **inode list**, file's inode number are record in directory file.

When you call system method `stat()` to get the status info about a file, the kernel will get the inode number from the directory file, then calculate the real disk address of the inode, then get the status info.

You can use `ls -i1a dirname` to get the inode info of a directory's files, here are output after i exec this command, the first column are the inode number:

```sh
$ ls -i1a .
8627654638 .
    633334 ..
8627654639 gitlab
```